# Create Framework to create a workflows system

Tags: .net, workflow

I want to make dynamic system to handle the business process through workflow cycle , i like to mange the system UI To be dynamic and configures by the system admin

[Dynamic Forms - E Payment - Offline Payment - Versions - validations - authorize ]
any advice would be appreciated

thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at Windows Workflow Foundation (WF)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj684582.aspx